# Camera.names not working in flash builder burrito

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, air, flex4.5

Im using camera class in my mobile application and I used Camera.names to fill my list and i tried to pass the selected value to getcamera() method but its not working.Here s my code

```
private function init():void
        {
            if (Camera.names.length == 0) {

                lab.text = "No camera attached";
                list.enabled = false;
                textArea.enabled = false;
            }
        }

        protected function list_changeHandler(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
        {
            var tList:List = evt.currentTarget as List;
                            var cameraName:String = tList.selectedIndex.toString();
            camera = Camera.getCamera(cameraName);
            vid=new Video();
            vid.attachCamera(camera);
            UIc.addElement(vid as IVisualElement);
            textArea.text = ObjectUtil.toString(camera);
        }
 <s:List id="list"
            dataProvider="{Camera.names as ArrayCollection}"
            width="200"
            change="list_change(event);" />
<s:Group id="UIc" x="68" y="253" width="368" height="281">
</s:Group>
```

Comment: does your mobile phone allow flash to use webcams, maybe it is disabled in settings..

Comment: Hi phillip,I'm using galaxy tab, there ll be front and rear camera rite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When compiling Air for mobile, you need to make sure that your [permissions are properly placed in the app xml file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html#WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d129d39606f2-8000).  In this case, you need to give your app permission to access the camera for it to work.

Comment: yes i have set the permissions and the default camera is opening up but if i want the front camera to open how do i do that?.Any ideas..

Answer (score 1):

On Android devices, you can only access the rear-facing camera.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera%28%29